# Is there a naming convention for keystore (java)

Tags: java, naming-conventions, keystore

I'm working with java keystores for the first time.  Is there a standard extension / suffix for a keystore?  Are they typically named .ks?  If it's a java keystore am I supposed to use .jks?  I would like to follow a naming convention if one is generally accepted.

Comment: how is this security related?

Comment: I was under the impression certificates were used for security solutions (digitally signing data, for instance).  Developers who work with security likely often work with certificates and if they are java developers probably work with java keystores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the key store type. The default type for Java is JKS so .jks makes sense. Other key store types exist such as PKCS12. Typical file extensions for PKCS12 key stores are .p12 and .pfx. Looking at the file extensions in the open file window for [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/), it considers .ks, .jks, .jceks, .p12, .pfx, .bks, and .ubr as possibilies. I've only ever encountered .jks, .p12, and .pfx myself however.

Answer (score 2):

For  Java keystores, IBM appears to suggest .jks

See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzatz/51/sec/secjavajsse.htm) that when specifying Java keystore settings, they use .jks as the extension.

Answer (score 0):

A format key must be converted into .jks format for use in the J2EE SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I just got into this question trying to guess why `Unity3d` didn't accept my Android keystore.
`name.key` doesn't work but `name.keystore` does, so I guess that `.keystore` is also a possible extension.